# Python2 porting to Python3: ConfigParser Exceptions - AttributeError on MissingSectionHeaderError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, configparser

I'm attempting to port a Python2.7 script to Python3.6+ and have hit a roadblock my google searching couldn't resolve. The issue is that a try: except: call below doesn't appear to work after doing some initial porting suggestions. I'm sure this is something simple; just escapes me at the moment.

**Python2.7** code: (worked)

```
import ConfigParser
logOutCfg = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

try:
 if (os.path.isfile(logOutfilename)) : logOutCfg.read(logOutfilename)
except ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError as e:
 pass
except ConfigParser.ParsingError as e:
 print(str(e))
 pass
```

**Python3.6** attempted code (doesn't work under Python 2.7):

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
logOutCfg = ConfigParser()

try:
 if (os.path.isfile(logOutfilename)) : logOutCfg.read(logOutfilename)
except ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError as e:
 pass
except ConfigParser.ParsingError as e:
 print(str(e))
 pass
```

The error reported by the script when running under Python2 is:

```
 File "<script>.py", line 242, in <function>
    except ConfigParser.MissingSectionHeaderError:
AttributeError: type object 'ConfigParser' has no attribute 'MissingSectionHeaderError'
```

I'm pretty sure I tried a bunch of different things; including: `except configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError` but with no joy.

What am I missing? I need the code to work in both Python2 and Python3 for the foreseeable future... at least the next 9 months.

Comment: What was the problem with `configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError`?

Comment: except configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError:
NameError: global name 'configparser' is not defined

Comment: Then you need to import it.

Comment: @mkrieger1
That appeared to work... not sure why I didn't think of it.

`import configparser
from configparser import ConfigParser

logOutCfg = ConfigParser()

try:
 if (os.path.isfile(logOutfilename)) : logOutCfg.read(logOutfilename)
except configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError as e:
 pass
except configparser.ParsingError as e:
 print(str(e))
 pass`

Comment: @Zitt Did either of the answers works for you? If so, would you mind accepting the one that did. Not only does this allow you to give back to the answerers for taking the time to answer your question, but it also serves to better the SO community by showing users the correct resolution for the issue you faced. This can be a great asset for other users facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

@mkrieger1 was right on the money. The key was to also 
**import configparser**

```
import configparser
from configparser import ConfigParser

logOutCfg = ConfigParser()

try:
 if (os.path.isfile(logOutfilename)) : logOutCfg.read(logOutfilename)
except configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError as e:
 pass
except configparser.ParsingError as e:
 print(str(e))
 pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Python 3.6 code is mostly correct. The only problem is that you are trying to grab the exceptions from the `ConfigParser` class instead of the `configparser` module. The main confusion here is most likely coming from the fact that name of the module changed in Python 3 to be more inline with [PEP8 standards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names). Originally, the `ConfigParser` module and class shared the same name, but this is not the case in Python 3.

The below code should work in Python 2 and 3.

```
try:
    import configparser
except ImportError: 
    import ConfigParser as configparser

logOutCfg = configparser.ConfigParser()

try:
    if (os.path.isfile(logOutfilename)):
        logOutCfg.read(logOutfilename)
except configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError as e:
    pass
except configparser.ParsingError as e:
    print(e)
```

Here is a quick breakdown of what is going on here.

```
try:
    import configparser
except ImportError: 
    import ConfigParser as configparser
```

Try to import the Python 3 `configparser` module. If in Python 2, this will raise an `ImportError`. We catch that, and instead import `ConfigParser` and alias it with `configparser`.

```
logOutCfg = configparser.ConfigParser()
```

Grab the `ConfigParser` class from the `configparser` module imported above, and instantiate it.

```
try:
    if (os.path.isfile(logOutfilename)):
        logOutCfg.read(logOutfilename)
except configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError as e:
    pass
except configparser.ParsingError as e:
    print(e)
```

Try to open the file as you were before, but instead of attempting to get the exceptions from the `ConfigParser` class, get them from the `configparser` module.